# Non-greedy regular expression in ed

Tags: regex

Is there a way to do non-greedy regular expression in ed?

I'm aware of the syntaxes for this VIM and perl-compatible regex; that's not what I'm asking about.  Sometimes plain vanilla ed is the most effective editing tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard GNU `ed` only supports very basic regular expressions as documented in [`ed(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ed), with no "non-greedy" modifier.

You might like `ex` (`vim -e`), which enables an ed-like interface in vi and vim.